# Error al pasar de php7.4.33 a php8.0

Tags: php

Soy nuevo en el foro. A ver si me pudierais ayudar porque voy un poco perdido.

Estoy en Siteground y quería pasar de la versión  de php que tengo actualmente, la 7.4.33, a una más moderna. Creo que tienen la 8.0.30.
El caso es que cuando lo intento me salta el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() in /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/haveanicedaydesign-theme/lib/woocommerce/woocommerce-setup.php:72 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/haveanicedaydesign-theme/functions.php(18): include_once() #1 /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/wp-settings.php(611): include('/home/customer/...') #2 /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/wp-config.php(83): require_once('/home/customer/...') #3 /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/customer/...') #4 /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/customer/...') #5 /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/customer/...') #6 {main} thrown in /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/haveanicedaydesign-theme/lib/woocommerce/woocommerce-setup.php on line 72
```

Esta es la línea 72 de woocommerce-setup.php

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 48;' ), 20 );
```

Si podéis guiarme y/o indicarme dónde puedo buscar información os estaría más que agradecido.
Un saludo. Samu.

Comment: ¿Tienes instalada la última versión de Woocommerce? Me parece que es totalmente compatible con PHP 8.

Comment: Hola. Sí, está todo actualizado. Tanto WooCommerce como la última de WordPress 6.4.1 De hecho, lo de pasar a 8.0 me saltó porque hay un plugin, Genesis blocks, que ya no me deja actualizar si no estoy en php8.0.

Comment: Parece ser un problema de tu tema, que estaría usando código obsoleto. Convendría revisar si no han publicado actualizaciones en ese sentido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si revisamos la documentación de PHP podemos ver que la función [`create_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php):

> Crear una función anónima (estilo lambda) [...]
> **Advertencia**
> Esta función ha sido **DEPREDICADA a partir de PHP `7.2.0` y ELIMINADA a partir de PHP `8.0.0`**. Se desaconseja encarecidamente confiar en esta función.

A partir de `PHP 7.4`, las nuevas formas que exiten para crear funciones anónimas son:

- [Funciones cierres](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php) (closures)

  > [...] permiten la creación de funciones que no tienen un nombre especificado. [...]
- [Funciones de flecha](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arrow.php)

  > [...] una sintaxis más concisa para las funciones anónimas. [...]

#### Solución:

Podes reescribir:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 48;' ), 20 );
```

Así:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function($cols) { return 48; }), 20 );
```

Comment: Genial. Muchas gracias. Ahora funciona pero me saltan dos warnings.  ´´Warning: Constant WP_DEBUG already defined in /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/wp-config.php on line 86

Warning: Constant FORCE_SSL_ADMIN already defined in /home/customer/www/haveanicedaydesign.com/public_html/wp-config.php on line 88  ´´ Voy a ver si encuentro el error. Gracias!